# How to set downtime for any specific nagios host for certain time from commandline through curl?

Tags: curl, scheduling, nagios

I have a curl script which will do the service/host notification disable/enable from the command line through curl.

But need to do that for scheduled downtime.

Can someone suggest me.

Okay it seems people failed to understand my requirement.Let's clarify few thing. I have script already with me.. which look like something like below:

curl -d " some key value pair(hostname,servicename" url "username:passowrd"

which will do the service/host notification on and off from the commandline. So I want use curl in this fashion to provide downtime for specific nagios server.

Above script is not working for it because downtime option of nagios taked more parameter and I tried to infuse those in the script..but it didn't work out that way.We need provide starttime,endtime and comment value too.

Plus I have tried curl's option called --form and --form-string with that script..not able to get through.

The besic idea is instead of going to the Nagios web interface, we want to done this thing from the command line(we have succeded for service/host service and notification).

Hope I am absolutely clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule a task through cron provided you use a Linux OS.

The [man cron](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cron+8) and [man crontab](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5) will help you figure out how this work. (And many, many tutorial on the internet).

Comment: Mvy you grossly misunderstood my question..or might not have the knowledge to answer it..

Comment: My bad, I did not understand it that way indeed.